# how to put ssl on aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Have a laravel application running on aws with elastic beanstalk, I have already created the load balancer, I have already released port 443 in both the load balancer and the security group, I have already registered the certificate, it has already been validated, but no configuration resolves, what to do?

Comment: " no configuration resolves" what do you mean? Any errors?

Comment: this already made several configurations looking at several different videos and none worked! I have a domain that I bought elsewhere and pointed it to aws, and now I need to activate ssl, I already got the free ssl from aws that has already been approved, but it does not propagate

Comment: You need to provide more info. How did you setup your load balancer for SSL? How do you test it?